# Neo4j and Mysql in Laravel Migrations

Tags: mysql, laravel, neo4j, laravel-migrations

I can migrate my neo4j migration file but when migrating my mysql file I get the message **"nothing to migrate"**. Even thought I my db in mysql is still empty.

My default database is neo4j so I'm running this command

> php artisan neo4j:migrate --database=mysql

and the result is still the same

Also when I change my default to mysql and run the basic migration command
the only thing that migrates is the migration table and nothing else.

[migration file for mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSugq.png)

Answer (score 0):

after switching the migration try the these commands

`php artisan migrate:refresh`

if this does not work go to your migrations table and drop the migrations and rerun the migration.

also if make sure to run these commands

```
        php artisan optimize
        php artisan clear-compiled
        php artisan cache:clear
        php artisan route:clear
        php artisan view:clear
        php artisan config:clear
```

Hope this helps